# How to format time.time() using strftime() in python

Tags: python

I have an `epoch` time that is in `Seconds.PartOfSecond` format e.g. `1581218900.17436`. How can this be used within `time.strftime()` ?

```
import time
curTime = time.time()
# Following is not correct but gives idea what i'm looking for
formattedTime = time.strftime('%A %B %e, %Y %t', curTime)
```

*Update* The answer this has been closed for is not imo an obvious replacement: how would one know we need to convert to `datetime.datetime`? The answer below is more to the point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need pass your second to `gmtime`

```
import time
s=time.gmtime(1581218900.17436)
time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", s)
'2020-02-09 03:28:20'
time.strftime('%A %B %e, %Y %t', s)
'Sunday February  9, 2020 \t'
```

Comment: Nice .  Any idea why it were so hard for me to find that info? What resources exist for something so basic?

Comment: @javadba https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

Comment: How to pass the parameter in `time.gmtime()` if we have store it in string format instead of integer format?